# Understanding the 'foreach' syntax for the keys of a hash

Tags: perl, foreach, hashmap

I have created a simple Perl hash

#### Sample.pl

```
$skosName = 'foo';
$skosId   = 'abc123';

$skosFile{'type'}{$skosId} = $skosName;
```

Later on I try to print the hash values using `foreach`.

This variant works

```
foreach $skosfile1type ( keys %{skosFile} ){

    print ...
}
```

While this one doesn't

```
foreach $skosfile1type ( keys %{$skosFile} ) {

    print ...
}
```

What is the difference between the two `foreach` statements?

In particular, what is the significance of the dollar sign `$` in the statement that doesn't work?

Is it something to do with scope, or perhaps my omission of the `my` or `our` keywords?

Comment: always `use strict; use warnings;` and declare all your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%{skosfile}` is the same as `%skosfile`. It refers to a hash variable with that name. Usually that form isn't used for a simple variable name, but it's allowable.

`%{$skosfile}` means to look at the scalar variable `$skosfile` (remember, in perl, `$foo`, `%foo`, and `@foo` are distinctvariables), and, expecting `$skosfile` to be a hashref, it returns the hash that the reference points to. It is equivalent to `%$skosfile`, but in fact any expression that returns a hashref can appear inside of `%{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `%{ $scalar }` is used to tell Perl that the type of `$scalar` is a hash ref and you want to undo the reference. That is why you need the dollar sign `$`: `$skosfile` is the variable you are trying to dereference.

In the same fashion, `@{ $scalar }` serves to dereference an array.

Although it does not work for complex constructions, in simple cases you may also abbreviate `%{$scalar}` to `%$scalar` and `@{$scalar}` to `@$scalar`.

In the case of the expression `keys %{$skosfile}`, `keys` needs a hash which you obtain by dereferencing `$skosfile`, a hash ref. In fact, the typical `foreach` loop for a hash looks like:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
  # do something with $key
}
```

When you iterate a hash ref:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %{ $hashref } ) {
  # do something with $key
}
```